# can i somehow download this text, and convert it to pdf or word or something like that?

Tags: text, download

Regards to all,

can i somehow download this text, and convert it to pdf or word or something like that?

https://www.pravno-informacioni-sistem.rs/SlGlasnikPortal/viewdoc?uuid=ffaa477f-e0a4-4e5d-ab26-8a68ec6eabdb

Answer (score 0):

Those scanned pages are not suitable for conversion to word.zip, It would not make the text editable only allow you to add text as comments, here I just saved 2 as CBZ so download the images and add to a zip.
[image]

***If you attempt OCR with such poor images you will get rubbish output***

[image]